# Activity indicator behavior not as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a table view that lists all states in the US. When a user clicks on a state, a list of river gauges for that state is generated from a web service call. The list is rendered in another table view controller. I am in the process of integrating an activity indicator to notify the user that there is network acitivity.

I have an object (GuageList) that holds the list of gauges as a mutable array. It is this object that makes the web service call and populates the array. The array is then used as the data source in the resulting table view controller. My first attempt at integrating an activity indicator was to place the initialization of this object in the destination table view controller that displays the gauges for a state. However, when I do this, I don't get expected results. When clicking on a state, there is a long pause, then the table view containing the list of gauges is displayed with the activity indicator briefly rendering in the destination controller.

Next, I tried placing the initialization of the GaugeList object in the initial table view controller (containing US states). My thoughts were to initialize the GaugeList object there, and pass it on the segue. This produced identical results.

Source segue code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sgShowStateRivers"]){

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading Rivers\nPlease wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert setOpaque:NO];
        [alert show];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityStatus = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 230, 50, 50)];
        activityStatus.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
        [activityStatus startAnimating];
        [alert addSubview:activityStatus];

        RiversByStateTableViewController *riversVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSArray *tempArray = (NSArray*)[groupedStates objectAtIndex:path.section];
        NSString *key = [tempArray objectAtIndex:path.row];

        NSString *stateID = [statesDict objectForKey:key];
        [riversVC setStateIdentifier:stateID];

        GaugeList *stateGauges = [[GaugeList alloc] initWithStateIdentifier:stateID andType:nil];
        [riversVC setStateGauges:stateGauges];

        [activityStatus stopAnimating];
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

In my destination, I simply use the stateGauges object to populate the table. My thoughts were that the stateGauges object would populate before the segue completed, but apparently I am incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! V

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the `prepareForSegue` delegate method to populate the `nextViewController` with data you already have in runtime memory. This is just a initial step before the segue actually occurs and the next view is presented to the user. The actions should be relatively quick.

*I suppose you could be holding up the main thread while you are downloading but that will essentially not allow you to update the views. I will assume you are making asynchronous web calls.*

You can think of this like `[view willDisplay]` and `[view didDisplay]`.

If you need to make a web call to populate your data, you might want to do this action when the user presses the State (cell, label, whatever). Present the view to show the download activity. Then after the web call has completed and the data has been verified, manually call the segue transition yourself using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueName" sender:someobject];`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can understand your point of calling the segue explicitly, however, when I do so, I get the following message:

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

This occurs when calling the segue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Would there be any way yo force the navigation to load the destination view controller upon clicking the cell in the source? Then load the data, while showing an activity indicator?

Comment: The problem here is that prepareForSegue is called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I suppose you could remove the seque mechanism all-together. You could just create the ViewController programmatically, populate the data, and then push the next ViewController on the navigation stack.